# Print Greek text inside field box using ZPL II

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I am trying to print greek text inside field box `^FB` with `^CI34`.

For example lets print this one that works:

```
^XA
^CF0,34
^CI34^FO5,5
^FH^FD Theta: _C8 ^FS
^XZ
```

It prints: `Theta: θ`

The code I use for `^FB`:

```
^XA
^CF0,34
^CI34^FO5,5
^FB300,2,0,L
^FH^FD Theta: _C8^FS
^XZ
```

It prints: `Theta:`

So where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

According to ZPL Programming guide `The ^FB command does not support complex text. For complex text support, use ^TB`

So in my case an example like this works:

```
^XA
^CF0,34
^CI34^FO5,5
^TBN,250,250
^FH^FD Theta: _C8^FS
^XZ
```